# Largest cone that can be inscribed in a sphere

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

> Prove that the volume of the largest cone that can be inscribed in a sphere of radius R is $\frac{8}{27}$ of the volume of the sphere.

**My Attempt**

[image]

r : radius of the base

h : height of the cone

$$
x=\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\implies h=R+x=R+\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\\
V(r)=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2(R+\sqrt{R^2-r^2})\\
V'(r)=\frac{\pi}{3}\big( 2r.(R+\sqrt{R^2-r^2})+r^2\frac{-r}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}} \big)\\=\frac{\pi}{3}r\big( 2R+2\sqrt{R^2-r^2})-\frac{r^2}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}} \big)\\=\frac{\pi}{3}r\big( \frac{2R\sqrt{R^2-r^2}+2R^2-2r^2-r^2}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}} \big)\\=\frac{-\pi}{3}r\big( \frac{2r^2-2R\sqrt{R^2-r^2}-2R^2}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}} \big)
$$

How do I proceed further and find the points where $V'(r)=0$ and prove the above statement ?

**Note:** I would like to stick with $r$ as the variable.

Comment: Find $r$ in terms of $x$ rather than the other way around.  $V = \frac {\pi}3 (R^2 - x^2)(R+x)$

Comment: @DougM thanx. but i was wondering how do i complete the calculation if i express it in terms of $r$ ?

Comment: Okay, You have a mistake in your last bit of simplifying.  Set the numerator equal to 0,  Isolate the term with the radical on one side of the equation.  Square both sides.  Solve for r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2R\sqrt {R^2 - r^2} +2R^2 - 3r^2 = 0\\
4R^2 (R^2 - r^2) =(2R^2 - 3r^2)^2\\
4R^4 - 4R^2r^2 = 4R^4 - 12R^2r^2 + 9r^2\\
8R^2 = 9r^2\\
r = \sqrt {\frac 89} R$

Answer (score 1):

I would write
$$V=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$$ then we get
$$r^2+x^2=R^2$$ and $$x+R=h$$ and so $$V(x)=\frac{1}{3}\pi(R^2-x^2)(x+R)$$
Or you can write: $$h=x+R$$ and $$x=\sqrt{R^2-r^2}$$ then we have
$$V=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2(\sqrt{R^2-r^2}+R)$$
$$V'(r)=1/3\,{\frac {\pi\,r \left( 2\,{R}^{2}-3\,{r}^{2}+2\,\sqrt { \left( R-r
 \right)  \left( R+r \right) }R \right) }{\sqrt { \left( R-r \right) 
 \left( R+r \right) }}}
$$
Solving the equation $$V'(r)=0$$ we get $$r_{opt}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}R}{3}$$

Comment: thanx. i was aware of this. but what if i choose $r$ as the variable then how do I complete the problem ? ie. how do i find the points where $V'(r)=0$ ?